# Should I say this differently?

Tags: word-choice

どうやって私は女の子と良い物事になせるのですか？

I'm pretty sure this makes sense, but I think I could say this a little better but I'm not sure how...?

Comment: ????? ---------

Comment: As a native speaker of English, I cannot guess what you are intending [物事]{ものごと} to mean, so it doesn't make sense to me either (sometimes Japanese constructed by English speakers is wrong in such a way it still makes sense to English speakers).

Comment: Assuming absence of sexual context, could it be どうやって女の子と仲良くなれるかな

Answer (score 5):

I'm a native speaker of Japanese and the sentence you mentioned sounds like this:

*How can I do something nice with a girl.*

Your sentence also has an atmosphere that you are talking about a kind of sexual things implicitly because of very abstract words like 物事 and なせる, otherwise you can choose more specific words since it is not embarrassing at all.

The sentence you mentioned make sense except for "物事に", you should say "物事を" in this case. Since this sentence involve a sexual thing, it is considered be used in casual scene. And "良い物事をなせるのですか" is too formal in the casual scene, you can say "良い事ができますか" instead. And you can omit 私は because it is clear this sentence is talking about yourself. So this can be a better sentence:

*どうやって女の子と良い事ができますか？*

Comment: 「どうやって女の子と良い事ができますか？」って、なんか不自然な感じしませんか？エッチな質問を丁寧語で聞いてる、みたいな？また、「どうやって」よりは「どうやったら」か「どうしたら」の方が日本語としては自然かと思いますが、いかがでしょうか。